# Hide first row in database query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a query that exports its results via email in a table format, i would really like to hide the first row of my data so it never gets exported with my results.

Example database table:

```
+------+--------+--------+
|Number|Language|Date    |
+------+--------+--------+
|2039  |text 1  |20/01/14|
+------+--------+--------+
|1     |text 2  |20/01/14|
+------+--------+--------+
|2     |text 3  |20/01/14|
+------+--------+--------+
```

The query that i am using at the moment is :

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as `count`, `lang`, DATE(NOW()) as `week_ending`
FROM
    mydata.table
WHERE
    `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL - 1 WEEK) AND
    `date` < DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY `lang` , DATE(NOW());
```

Is it possible to hide the row **2039  text 1  20/01/14**

Comment: You can use OFFSET 1 in conjunction with a really big LIMIT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`` SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`,`lang`, DATE(NOW()) as `week_ending` FROM mydata.table WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 WEEK) AND `date` < DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY `lang`, DATE(NOW()) LIMIT 1,x; ``

replace x with a number big enough to contain all your records.

or use, instead of x, 18446744073709551615, that is maximum value of big INT unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which row you think appears first depending on the order. If no order is specified, you usually get your records based on insertion order.

If you are ordering by Number column in descending then add where clause

```
   WHERE Number < MAX(Number)
```

If you are ordering by Number in ascending then add where clause

```
   WHERE Number > MIN(Number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  LIMIT 1, N  at the End of query.

Where N is the number of rows  you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

if 'number' is the primary key you can get the same result using following query also.

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(*) as 'count', t1.language, DATE(NOW()) as 'week_ending'
FROM

(select * from 'mydata.table') t1 left join 
(select * from 'mydata.table' limit 1) t2 on t1.number = t2.number
where t2.number is null

And
t1.date > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL - 1 WEEK)
    AND t1.date < DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY t1.language , DATE(NOW());
```